Lint error: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions
I'm getting the following error at countryMap.get(tradeId)?.map((companies) => { : Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions
const calculate = (countryId: string) => {
    let rev = 0;
    countryMap.get(countryId)?.map((companies) => {
        rev += Number(companies.profitAndLoss);
        rev = Number(rev.toFixed(2));
    })
    return rev;
}

Could someone please help me understand the cause and how to solve it?

Why are you using .map and ignoring the array it creates?

Its for a very specefic scenario, i dont need the reduced array, but need the profitAndLoss from the reduced array

Yes, so don't create the array you don't need. That's what the linter is telling you: the expression (thing.map) results in a value (a new array) which is unused.

Thanks, used a for loop instead. It has worked now

I believe you can use reduce in this case, also here you're not using the variable countryId which could be the error. Also where does tradeId come from ?
const calculate = (countryId: string) => {
    return  countryMap.get(countryId)?.reduce((rev, companies) => {
        profit = Number(companies.profitAndLoss);
        return  Number((rev + profit).toFixed(2));
    })
}

